# Is there a way to store a String with markup in the strings.xml?

Tags: android, html, textview

I need to render some text with simple markup `<b> <i>` etc. and it looks like [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) should do the trick for displaying it, but I'm wondering if it's possible to store the string *with the markup in the Strings.xml or if I have to just keep this string in my Java file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this link: [Formatting and Styling](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling), particularly the "Styling with HTML markup" subsection.

After getting the text via `Html.FromHtml()`, set the text to a `TextView` using the [`setText(CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29) method, passing in `TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE` for the 2nd parameter.

Comment: @DrDredel: IOW, you can just use `<b>`, `<i>`, and `<u>` inline normally. If, however, you need more markup than that, you will need to store the string elsewhere, then use `Html.fromHtml()` to load it in. A rough roster of the supported tags for `fromHtml()` can be found here: http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: That's great to know, thanks... but I was specifically trying to figure out what Filipe Batista chimed in with; namely, how to store the HTML in my string.xml so as to not have string.xml choke all over itself.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: Except his answer is wrong. You do not need a `CDATA`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, So... what's the answer?  I tried setting my string value (in strings.xml) to something like "foo <b>bar</b>" and passing the value along to Html.fromHtml(), as well as just setting it as the text for my TextView and both approaches simply ignore the markup.  The CDATA solution works, so, if it's "wrong" then please advise as to what the correct approach is.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel See my edited answer. `Html.fromHtml()` will return a `Spanned` object and you need to communicate to the `TextView` you are giving it a `Spanned` object.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: See my answer, which is straight from the documentation that Mr. Robinson posted.

Answer (score 5):

Step #1: Have a `strings.xml` file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="welcome">Welcome to <b>Android</b>!</string>
</resources>
```

You will note that this is from [the documentation that Jason Robinson linked to](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling).

Step #2: There is no step #2 for using this from layouts, the manifest, etc. as `@string/welcome`. You are already done.

Step #2b: If you need this value in Java, use `getText()` instead of `getString()`.

Comment: Good point with `getText()`, `getString()` will remove HTML markup.

Comment: ok, well... as it happens this STILL doesn't work in my case, because I actually need that string as a string so that I can do some replacements on it, and then eventually run it through format().  So, the CDATA approach is still the only solution that appears to be the correct one in my case. I suppose my case may be slightly unusual. I agree that if one were to need that String as a flat, un-editable piece of HTML, that your approach is obviously the more straight ahead one.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: " because I actually need that string as a string so that I can do some replacements on it, and then eventually run it through format()." -- which can be handled by escaping the tags, as described in the documentation that Jason Robinson linked to. If `CDATA` tactically covers your situation, fine, but I'd be a bit worried that since the docs have an alternative solution in mind, something might happen with resource processing in the future that breaks the `CDATA` trick.

Comment: ah! I see. Very nice. Ok, I guess this is the "correct" approach, though I have to say, it still looks a lot uglier than the CDATA approach (which itself wasn't all that pretty to begin with).

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: Oh, yeah, no arguments there.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the strings in

```
<![CDATA[ ...html... ]]>
```

try something like this

```
<string name="html">
<![CDATA[
<p>paragraph</p>
<b>bold stuff</b>
]]>
</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your string marked up with html tags, like:

```
<big>Welcome to <b>Android</b></big>! <small>Enjoy marking up your text</small>
...
```

Then set it as spannable text in a text view as below:

```
Spanned spannedText = Html.fromHtml(yourMarkedUpString);
yourTextView.setText(spannedText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

No matter your string text is in a constant literal, variable or `string.xml` resource file, below tags are available out of the box:

```
<p>
<div> handled exactly like <p>
<br>
<b>
<i>
<strong> (bug on some Android versions: generates italic)
<em> (bug on some Android versions: generates bold)
<u>
<tt>
<dfn>
<sub>
<sup>
<blockquote>
<cite>
<big>
<small>
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">  (buggy font size sometimes gets ignored)
<h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>
<a href="...">
<img src="...">
```

Want more tags like `<center>` and `<strike>`?

- consider using a [library](https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview).

Or maybe you are a [full doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) fan?